# PWM output vs Digital output

Tags: digital-logic, pwm, power-consumption, duty-cycle

Could I use a PWM output as a digital output? For example to act like an on-off signal by varying the duty cycle between 0 and 100%.
Does it involve any difference in power consumption?

Comment: PWM is usually used as a way to use a digital output to produce an analog signal. Using it in PWM mode to make a digital signal instead of just putting it back in its normal digital mode is over-complicating things.

Answer (score 2):

> For example to act like an on-off signal by varying the duty cycle between 0 and 100%.

Sure, a PWM that's on 100% of the time is just a "high" output. Same with 0% and "low".

However, this sounds like something you ask in context of a microcontroller. I've yet to meet a microcontroller where you have a pin that you can connect to a PWM unit, but not directly use it as GPIO. So, I bet there's an easier solution to what you want.

We couldn't possibly tell you anything about power consumption, because that fully depends on the device you're dealing with. However, for the above reason, I don't think this is relevant. You really might want to ask a new question where you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

A PWM output will give you a PWM signal. It's operating frequency will be limited by the clock frequency and the divider options that the microcontroller features. If one of the available configurations suits your application then you can generate a continuous pulse train at that frequency with variable PWM. You haven't changed or invented anything new so far.

Most PWM outputs can be configured as digital outputs and directly switched on and off.

> Does it involve any difference in power consumption?

Generally power is consumed in *switching* as small capacitors have to be charged and discharged. Higher frequency consumes more power and generates more heat.